# IWMPPlaylistArray.Item(index) throws IO exception on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, com, windows-8.1, windows-media-player

I have a simple application enumerating Windows Media Player playlists. It just gets name for each playlist and prints it to the console:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mediaPlayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer { uiMode = "invisible" };
        var allPlaylists = mediaPlayer.playlistCollection.getAll();

        Console.WriteLine("Found {0} wmp playlists");
        for (int i = 0; i < allPlaylists.count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                IWMPPlaylist wmpPlaylist = allPlaylists.Item(i); //Exception here!
                Console.WriteLine("Playlist with index {0} has name '{1}'", i, wmpPlaylist.name);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to get playlist with index {0} with error '{1}'", i, e.Message);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It works fine on Windows 8 but throws exception on Windows8.1 on attempt to get the playlist item from the IWMPPlaylistArray collection:

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException was caught
  HResult=-2147024893
  Message=The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
  Source=WMP_POC
  StackTrace:
       at WMPLib.IWMPPlaylistArray.Item(Int32 lIndex)
       at WMP_POC.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
  InnerException:

Also it works fine for user created playlists even on Windows 8.1 but for predefined playlists like 'All Music', 'All Video' the exception is occurs.

Please, help!

Comment: I see it.  No knob you could tweak, catch and move on with your life.  Call Microsoft Support if you can't live with it.

Comment: I have posted question on the msdn support forum - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/365e7437-4f25-43f6-b242-1981f1d3cf3d/iwmpplaylistarrayitemindex-throws-io-exception-on-windows-81?forum=fordesktopru. But no answer for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have investigated more deeply and I have found that “All Music” playlist which should reside in the “C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player\Sync Playlists\en-US\00057566” is simply absent on Windows 8.1 while on Windows 8 it exists. And this is seems to be the root cause of the issue.

As I already mentioned on Windows 8.1 the problem exists only for predefined playlists and at the end of the day I have found out the following workaround which is seems to be working on the Windows 8.1. If you want to get "All Music" playlist just use the following code:

```
IWMPPlaylist allMusicPlaylist = mediaPlayer.mediaCollection.getByAttribute("MediaType", "Audio");
```

By changing "MediaType" attribute according to [the table on the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564781%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can get "All Video", "All Pictures" etc. predefined playlists.